# htaccess ExpiresDefault conditional

Tags: .htaccess, cache-control, apache2.4, mod-expires

I have in my Apache 2.4's `.htaccess` the following:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

However, pages that start with `today_` (files actually *not* present on the server) should not be cached. How would you write that condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Apache 2.4 and you should be :) You can simply use a condition statement. I think these are overlooked a lot. I would approach it this way.

```
#if URL contains today_ turn it off
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /today_/">
    ExpiresActive Off
</If>
<Else>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</Else>
```

Comment: What version do you have of apache? and does anything happen

Comment: wait.. for some reason the following regex is not matching well: `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /(today_|hoy_|hoje_)/">`

Comment: I think it is not matching because the file is not present in the file system (mod_rewrite)